# The type parameter E is hiding the type E. Tried different variations and still couldnt fix

Tags: java, generics, types

I am practicing generics and i did the following.

Created a class called man as below.

```
public class Man {
    int hands=2;
    int legs=2;
    boolean alive;

    public Man(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        alive=b;
    }
}
```

created a class called person

```
public class Person<Man> {
    Man p;
    String name;


    public Person(Man p, String name) {
        this.p = p;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

tried to instantiate a person of type `String` or int as below and it didn't throw and error.

```
Person<String> p1 = new Person<String>(new String("test"), "test1");
Person<Integer> p2=new Person<>(1,"test");
```

Now i changed the class signature to

```
 public class Person<T extends Man>{}
```

And i can no longer create a person of type `String`. Why did this happen? I want person class to strictly be a man and not a mutant which is a subclass of Man.. How do i do it?

I even tried doing the below

```
public abstract class AliveBeing<T>{}
```

made AliveBeing the superclass of `Man` and then tried

```
public class Person<Man> extends AliveBeing<Man>{}
```

Even now, the `Man` in `Person<Man>` has the yellow line under it (The type parameter Man is hiding the type `Man`) and the Man in AliveBeing does not.

Why is the compiler only confused about the `Man` in `Person<Man>`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you've got about four different questions in there, but I'll give this a try!

> Now i changed the class signature to
>
> `public class Person<T extends Man>{}`
>
> And i can no longer create a person of type string. Why did this happen?

Because by writing `Person<T extends Man>` you specified that the type parameter `T` to person must extend `Man` (which also allows it to be `Man`).  So, if `Milkman` and `Postman` all extend `Man`, then `Person<Milkman>`, `Person<Postman>` and `Person<Man>` are all valid types, but `Person<String>` is not, because `String` does not extend `Man`.

> `public class Person<Man> extends AliveBeing<Man>{}`
>
> Why is the compiler only confused about the Man in Person?

Because in this declaration, you're using `Man` the way most people would use `T` or `E` - that is, it's the type parameter, not an actual class.  You're making a generic `Person` class, where `Man` can be replaced by any type at all.

The compiler warning says that by doing this, you're masking the actual definition of the class `Man`, which now can't be used within the `Person` generic class definition.  It's almost certainly not what you intended to do, which is why the compiler is warning you.

Comment: hmm.. thanks you.. so now im curious.. how do i write a generic class that takes only Man as the generic type?

Comment: What do you mean?  How is it generic if the only possible value of the generic parameter is `Man`?  Or do you mean you want something like `public class Person extends AliveBeing<Man>`, which is NOT itself a generic class, even though it extends a generic class?

Comment: emm..Let me think about it.